# $\sum_{j=1}^n|Z_1\cdots Z_j|$ converges in $L^1$ and a.s. for $Z_i\sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I'm trying to prove that $\sum_{j=1}^n|Z_1\cdots Z_j|$ converges in $L^1$ and a.s. as $n\to\infty$, for $Z_i\sim N(0,1)$ independently. I think I should use that I have a sum of nonnegative r.v.'s with expectation $\sqrt{\frac2{\pi}}^{\ n}$, which converges to $0$ exponentially. Is there a theorem that gives both $L^1$ and a.s. convergence of a sum of nonnegative r.v.'s with expectations that tend to $0$ exponentially? If not, do you know another approach that can work here?

Comment: Ambiguous:  $|Z_1...Z_j|$ Is it a sum or product or something else?

Comment: @herbsteinberg $\sum_{j=1}^n|Z_1\cdots Z_n|=\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{k=1}^j|Z_k|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us look at $\mathbb{L}^1$ convergence. All you need to prove is that this sequence converges absolutely, that is

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{E} (|Z_1 \ldots Z_n|) < +\infty.$$

This criterion is sharp in this case since all increments are nonnegative.

For the almost sure convergence, let us notice that this sequence of random variables $S_n$ converges in $[0,+\infty]$, simply because it is nondecreasing. All we need to prove for the a.s. convergence is that

$$\mathbb{P} \left(\lim_{n \to + \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n |Z_1 \ldots Z_k| = +\infty \right) = 0.$$

But we know that, by the monotone convergence theorem and Fubini's theorem,

$$\mathbb{E} \left(\lim_{n \to + \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n |Z_1 \ldots Z_k| \right) 
= \mathbb{E} \left(\sum_{n \geq 1} |Z_1 \ldots Z_n| \right) 
= \sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{E} \left( |Z_1 \ldots Z_n| \right),$$

which we have already computed at the first step.